# How do you do Pointer arithmetic with multidimensional arrays in C?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

How would I uses pointers in a multidimensional array? In each direction how would I replace what I have done with pointer arithmetic? I have defined my ptr as *location. I think I need to make this change because I am getting segmentation faults when totalHops>400. Thus, explicitly changing x, y, z each time must be causing this error. Context: I am moving a particle in an L by L by L 3D space. I have a random number generator to determine whether the particle moves left, right, up, down, back or forth each time the particle randomly moves location. (Note I have designed the system to have periodic boundary conditions).

```
const int L = 10;
int N = L*L*L;
const int totalHops = 200; 
int sites[L][L][L] = {};
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
int tracker[N] = {};
int *location;
location = &sites[0][0][0];
for (int i = 1; i <= totalHops; i++) // the random walk //
    {
        int direction = randomInt(6); // six possible directions to move //
        // along x //
        if (direction == 0) { // move in negative direction //
            x -= 1;
            if (x == -1)
            {
                x = L-1;
            }
        }
        if (direction == 1) { // move in positive direction //
            x +=1;
            if (x == L) 
            {
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        // along y //
        if (direction == 2) { // move in negative direction //
            y -= 1;
            if (y == -1)
            {
                y = L-1;
            }
        }
        if (direction == 3) { // move in positive direction //
            y +=1;
            if (y == L) 
            {
                y = 0;
            }
        }
        // along z //
        if (direction == 4) { // move in negative direction //
            z -= 1;
            if (z == -1)
            {
                z = L-1;
            }
        }
        if (direction == 5) { // move in positive direction //
            z +=1;
            if (z == L) 
            {
                z = 0;
            }
        }
    tracker[i] = sites[x][y][z]; }
```

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: My suggestion is: Don't. Use normal array indexing syntax. The compiler will translate it to pointer arithmetic anyway (remember that for any array *or* pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`).

Comment: As for the problem you have, use a debugger to catch the crash as and when it happens, and locate where in your code it happens. When the debugger caught it and you found it in your code, then examine all involved variables and their values. My guess is that you have some index out of bounds.

Comment: `int tracker[N] = {};` etc isn't valid C. What non-standard settings do you have enabled, on which compiler?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for you suggestion. I only started programming in feb this year, so I have little experience with a debugger. But will try using one again. Thanks

Comment: @Lundin `int tracker[N] = {};` does this not automatically fill this array with zeros? Or shoudl I explicitly write `int tracker[N] = {0}`?  I am failrly new to this, so forgive me if I dont answer your question correctly. I code on mac using visula code studio so I think its a gcc compiler

Comment: Update: I have run a debugger and It says for `tracker[i] = sites[x][y][z];` "Exception has occurred. EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5fc00000)" Does anyone know what this means? Thanks

Comment: @asmit98 The initializer list has to contain at least one item, so yes `{0}` is correct. But since `{}` compiles you aren't using standard C but some extension. gcc gnu11 most likely, that's the default mode of gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind, that although `C` accommodates array notation such as 2D, 3D, ..., nD arrays to make working with them more natural from a human readability perspective.  But in memory, arrays are actually created as a single block of contiguous memory.  For example your array:

```
const int L = 10;
...
int sites[L][L][L] = {0}; //(using {0} is an idiomatic way to init. arrays to all 0
```

Is arranged in memory as 10*10*10 sequential sizeof(int) sections of memory, starting at the memory location pointed to by `sites`.

```
| | | | | | | | | ...| | | | 
^                        ^
sites + 0                sites + (10*10*10 - 1)*sizeof(int)
```

Because of this fact, pointer math becomes pretty straight forward:

```
*(sites + 0)   is equivalent to sites[0][0][0]
*(sites + 1)   is equivalent to sites[0][0][1]
*(sites + 2)   is equivalent to sites[0][0][2]
...
*(sites + 10)  is equivalent to sites[0][1][0]
...
*(sites + 100) is equivalent to sites[1][0][0]
...
*(sites + 998) is equivalent to sites[9][9][8]
*(sites + 999) is equivalent to sites[9][9][9]
```

The pattern between the pointer notation and array notation becomes very apparent, as the number added to the beginning of the array correlates with the arrangement of indexes in the array notation.

Based on this basic form, you can derive a way to use pointer math to represent multidimensional arrays, in your case then, using `int *location;` initialized to the beginning of `sites` can be used to track (or determine) what element of the `3D` array is being looked at, or modified.

This could apply nicely to your specific problem in that tracking `totalHops`, and making decisions based on values outside the range of `0 - 9` in any direction for `x,y,z` may be more difficult than making decisions based on notation such as `*(sites + 400)` (per your description in OP).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that insightful and clearly demonstrated. I used a pointer in my one dimensional problem of this exact nature (with only two possible directions to move in). Would it not make any difference for the memory and the program to avoid segmentation fault or error message "Abort trap: 6" if I were to implement pointers like you have demonstrated above? @ryyker Thanks again for your help

Comment: @asmit98 - As stated, the expressions `sites[i][j][k]` is exactly equivalent to `*(sites + ijk)`, so yes, the logic would be the same, and criteria for choosing one expression form or the other would be which will be easier to programmatically determine an out of bounds condition in your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

So in conclusion to my segmentation fault, I have simply used the wrong variable in my tracker array. But nonetheless, as a fairly new programmer it was good to have thse conversations and thank you for all of your help! I am glad to have explored both the uses of indexing and pointers.

Array needed to be

```
int tracker[totalHops] = {};
```